# java code to extract section of text from huge file, using only min RAM

Tags: java, file, text, file-io

I have huge text files-- each file is as big as 10 GB.

Now, I have with me 2 strings `"StringNumber1"` and `"StringNumber2"`

"Stringnumber1" occurs exactly once in each text file, and `"StringNumber2"` is always after `"StringNumber1"` (although there can be more than 1 occurrence of `"StringNumber2"` in the text file).

I want to extract all the text occurring in each file, starting from the match for "StringNumber1" and up to that occurrence of `"StringNumber2"` that occurs immediately after the matching "StringNumber1" (The content between these occurrences of `"StringNumber1"` and `"StringNumber2"` may be few bytes to many Gigabytes)...

How do I extract such content, using least RAM? I want to do this in Java.

Comment: looks like a job for regexes - but you need to feed a stream to them.

Comment: Is just using a `BufferedReader` not good enough?

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having difficulty with?  Do you know you are having a memory problem or that you are concerned you might have one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is just using a `BufferedReader` not good enough? Well i never had the problem to read really large files. Do you get some kind of error when using this approch?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Read {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("someFile"));
        try {
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                if(line.contains("String 1")) {
                    // ...
                } else if (line.contains("String 2")) {
                    // ...
                }               
                line = br.readLine();
            }       
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would write the loop as `for(String line; (line = br.readline()) != null;)`

Answer (score 1):

To minimise RAM usage, copy the data to another file(s).  Start a new file when you see the first string and stop when your see the second.  This means your heap usage is small (a few MB) and constant (regardless of the amount of data copied)